# Открыть Android приложение при переходе на ссылку

Tags: java, android, ссылки

Нужно чтобы при клике на ссылку в браузере открывалось Android приложение, установленное на данном устройстве. Как это можно реализовать? То есть если в браузере открываешь ссылку на видео в ютубе, предлагают открыть Приложение ютуба. Должно быть что-то подобное

Comment: примерно так)) http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/mybrowser.php

Comment: )))))))) ))))))))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если, допустим, ссылка ведет в Google Play, то можно сделать так:

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        if(URI.parse(url).getHost().replaceAll("www\\.").equals("play.google.com")) {
            for(String keyValuePair : url.split("\\?")[1].split("&")) {
            String[] kv = keyValuePair.split("=");
            if(kv[0].equals("id")) {
                Intent launchIntent = getPackageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(kv[1]);
                if(launchIntent != null){
                    startActivity(launchIntent);
                }
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Приложение не установлено", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
            //не нужно загружать страницу
            return true;
        }
        else {
            //это не ссылка на Google Play, грузим страницу
            return false;
        }
    }
});
```

Здесь мы ставим слушатель на `WebView`. В метод `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` приходит нажатая ссылка, мы проверяем, ведет ли она на Google Play или нет, если ведет, то страницу эту мы не грузим, так как собираемся по своему обработать. Как обработать? Обрезаем в ссылке все, что идет после вопросительного знака, обрезаем по знаку `&`, получаем массив ключ=значение, циклом ищем ключ `id`, когда находим - берем его значение (пекейж) и пытаемся создать интент, который будет приложение с таким пекейжем открывать. **Если такого приложения нет, то интент будет `null`**.

Из метода `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` мы обязаны вернуть `boolean` обработки - проще говоря (как, обычно, везде) нужно вернуть `true` если мы обработали что-то по своему и нам не надо то, что выполняется по умолчанию. В этом случае я возвращаю `true` когда ссылка ведет в Google Play, то есть ссылка на маркет в `WebView` не откроется. Вы можете перенести это в проверку на установленное приложение, чтобы ссылка на маркет открывалась только тогда, когда приложение не установлено. Для этого перенесите `return false` в проверку интента на `null` (приложение не установлено, разрешим загрузку), а `return true` - туда, где вызывается переход `startActivity` (приложение установлено, страницу не грузим)

**UPD**

Или я не до конца прочитал и ринулся в бой, или автор не сразу описал суть задачи полностью, или я что-то не понял, ну, да, не важно. Конкретно по YouTube, вроде как все просто, думаю, по этому примеру можно расширить функционал самому.

Просто, так же проверяем, ведет ли ссылка на видео YouTube и, если это так, то открываем приложение. В этом примере в самом `WebView` видео откроется только тогда, когда приложение YouTube не установлено на устройстве.

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        String host = URI.parse(url).getHost().replaceAll("www\\.");
        //хоста у ютуба 2
        if(host.equals("youtube.com") || host.equals("youtu.be")) {
           //избегаем параметров, только ссылки на видео
           if(url.split("\\?")[0].contains("/watch?")) {
               if(getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.google.android.youtube") != null) {
                   Intent videoIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                   videoIntent.setData(url);
                   videoIntent.setClassName("com.google.android.youtube", "com.google.android.youtube.WatchActivity");
                   startActivity(videoIntent);
                   return true;
               }
           }
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

В файле Android.Manifest нужно прописать применительно к активити приложения

```
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
                <data
                    android:host="www.example.com" //любая нужная ссылка
                    android:pathPrefix="/main2"
                    android:scheme="http"/>
            </intent-filter>
```